# How does 'pg_tablespace_size' works?

Tags: postgresql-11

I ran following command and got followings, but a bit confuesed about table size manipulation becaue I do not know how does pg_tablespace_size work:

```
my_db=> select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('my_table'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 123 GB
(1 row)

my_db=> select pg_size_pretty(pg_indexes_size('my_table'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 34 GB
(1 row)

my_db=> select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('my_table'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 27 GB
(1 row)
```

**rest_space = pg_total_relation_size('my_table') - (pg_indexes_size('my_table') + pg_relation_size('my_table'))**

But I do not know where is rest_space (62 GB), I would be grateful if someone explain this.

Comment: Please re-phrase the title, as your question doesn’t seem to mention anything about tablespaces

Answer (score 1):

`pg_relation_size(<tablename>)` is actually shorthand for `pg_relation_size(<tablename>,’main’)` (see the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE)). There are also the free space map (fsm), visibility map (vm), and init forks that factor into the full size.

I think you would get the correct results if you did `pg_total_relation_size() = pg_table_size() + pg_indexes_size()`